# Submitting a POST object

Tags: spring, jsp

I spent the whole weekend searching the net on my problem. It seems like  I am missing something really silly, but I failed to pick it up.

Here's the problem. I sent an object to a JSP and on the JSP I could see its content. I them I submitted the form. Back in the controller, it shows the object is overwritten/recreated. I can't seem to understand. I  checked the logs on my Tomcat but I do not see any error...

On my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());


    Catalog catalog = catalogService.getCatalogByCategory(Catalog.CatalogCategory.ALL);

    model.addAttribute("catalog", catalog);
    model.addAttribute("numberOfItemsAdded", "500");
    return "welcome";
}`
```

and in my JSP I have the following:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="catalog">
            <form:hidden path="id"/>

            <div id="products" class="row list-group">
                <c:forEach var="orderItem" items="${catalog.orderItems}">

                    <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt=""/>

                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                                        ${orderItem.name}</h4>

                                <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                                        ${orderItem.description}
                                </p>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                        <p class="lead">
                                            R ${orderItem.price}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                        <label for="${orderItem.id}" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart <input
                                                type="checkbox" id="${orderItem.id}" name="orderItem.addedToCart"
                                                class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 pull-right">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right">

                        <input type="submit"
                               class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-primary"
                               value="Next" name="action" formmethod="POST"
                               formaction="confirmList"/>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form:form>`
```

After pressing "Next", which submits the form data to a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/confirmList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String confirmList(@ModelAttribute Catalog catalog, @ModelAttribute String numberOfItemsAdded) {
    System.out.println("\n\n------>catalog = " + catalog);
    System.out.println("\n\n------>numberOfItemsAdded = " + numberOfItemsAdded);
    List<OrderItem> selectedItems = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
    for (OrderItem orderItem : catalog.getOrderItems()) {
        if (orderItem.isAddedToCart()) {
            selectedItems.add(orderItem);
        }
    }
    //model.addAttribute("numberOfItemsAdded", selectedItems.size());
    return "welcome";
}
```

`

The `System.out.println(...)` output the following:

```
------>catalog = Catalog{id=1, name='null', category='null', orderItems=null}


------>numberOfItemsAdded =
```

Those are empty outputs.... :'(

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.....

Comment: I can see that only the id of the Catalog is binded, the rest of the fields are null because you are not binding them in the form. You need to bind them in the same way as the id using he spring form tags such as <form:input> etc. As regards to the numberOfItemsAdded, don't pass it as a @ModelAttribute, it's already in the ModelMap from the GET method so you can retrieve it from the modelMap in your Post method

Comment: Thank you so much, George! This totally solves my problem! Thank you once more!

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered in a comment line by George. All I had to do is hide/bind those null fields.

It is very concerning that we use the term 'hidden' to also mean 'ignore' or 'leave as is'. But anyway, the solution above did exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks to the Community